# I have an array of objects that I fetch from API and its contents are in String format. How do I convert it into a date?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using moment library and this is what my array looks like.

data:

```
[
            {
              "id": "610",
              "description": "New Test",
              "start": "2021-08-04T14:20:00.000Z",
              "end": "2021-08-04T15:30:00.000Z",
              "profile": {
                "firstName": "Steve",
                "lastName": "Tene"
              }
            },
            {
              "id": "610b",
              "description": "test",
              "start": "2021-08-03T13:30:00.000Z",
              "end": "2021-08-03T14:30:00.000Z",
              "profile": {
                "firstName": "Steve"
              }
            },
      ]
```

here's what i tried, but it does nothing because the map only loops through the array without changing.

```
data.content.map(x=>moment(x.start).toDate())
```

How do i write a loop such that I can convert the start and end string to an actual time?

Edit: I have tried the solutions you all suggested thank you for quick response. But I get this error whenever I try anything, so i thought I will include more code..

Error:  Cannot assign to read only property 'start' of object '#'

```
  const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const { searchavailable: data } = await searchAvailability()
      console.log(data.content)
      if (data) {
        data.content = data.content.forEach(x => {
          x.start = moment(x.start).toDate();
          x.end = moment(x.end).toDate();
      });
        setSchedule(data.content)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [schedule])
```

**FIXED!!!!**

Thank you all for your comments I was able to do it, I had to use deepClone from lodash and it works!

Comment: `data.content = data.content.map(x=>moment(x.start).toDate())`

Comment: I have tried it but I get an error.... Cannot assign to read only property 'content' of object '#<Object>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you shouldn't directly mutate data in React. like this

```
data.content = data.content.forEach...
```

It's good idea to create a copy before modification.

```
data.content = [...data.content].forEach
```

And instead of reassigning new value to `data.content` you may store the modified data in a new variable.

So following piece of code should work for you.

```
const dataContent = [...data.content].map(x => {
  // Perform data modifications here, for instance
  x.start = new Date(x.start);
  return x;
});

setSchedule(dataContent);
```

Or

```
const dataContent = [...data.content];
dataContent.forEach(x => {
  // Perform data modifications here, for instance
  x.start = new Date(x.start);
});
setSchedule(dataContent);
```

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return anything, it makes no sense to assign the result. You're thinking of `map()`

Comment: @Barmar yeah my bad, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I have tried these solutions as well, its the same issue. It says "Cannot assign to read only property 'start'"  ........ this  is confusing because I have not put any read only properties, It's just some plane data I'm fetching via graphql

Comment: That's strange. Are you using TypeScript? or are these objects are an instance of a class? Otherwise above approaches should work for a plain JS object

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the start and end times, you need to assign to those properties. Use a `forEach()` loop to iterate over the array, then assign the appropriate places.

```
data.content.forEach(x => {
    x.startDate = moment(x.start).toDate();
    x.endDate = moment(x.end).toDate();
});
```

Comment: I have tried this as well and this is the error,  Cannot assign to read only property 'start' of object '#<Object>'

Comment: The code that created the objects declared those properties read-only, so you're not supposed to replace them. Either assign new properties or create new objects.

Comment: I have renamed the const to let and it still does not work. I did not manually set any properties, it's just fetching from the server. Is there a way i can remove the read only property?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `const`. That prevents assigning the variable, it has nothing to do with properties.

Comment: Is this an array of class objects? It may have its own methods for updating the properties.

Comment: No it is just a simple array as shown in the question initially. just an array of objects. I've never faced this issue before I do modify the response data, it is not working on this project.

Comment: Than I'm not sure why it make those properties read-only. Anyway, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty for how to modify the property descriptor to add `writable: true`

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(x, "start", {writable: true});`

Answer (score 2):

No libs needed.  Just pass the string to [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
data.content.forEach(x => {
   x.start = new Date(x.start);
   x.end = new Date(x.end);
});
```

Comment: This throws away all the other data in the array.

Comment: yeah. my bad, i just copy/pasted...  now it loops through the array reassigning the string value.